# Angular JS - Rest API - Authorization sent from browser but not received in server

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I have a spring boot application with basic spring security enabled.  And I have a web application written in Angular JS

When I make a rest call, I can clearly see the Authorization header being passed. But in the server, it displays the header as Null.

**P.S** This happens only in my machine ( yeh the same old story ) but appears to be working everywhere else.

**Request Header**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW5Ac211LmVkdS5zZzpleUXXXXXXXXXXXSmhaRzFwYmtCemJYVXVaV1IxTG5ObkXXXXXXXXXXXXTmpReGZRLnXXXXXXOExJNF80MjBjMTZMUTFWX2JLR1p1VjM5SmZ3dllXbkxVTmc4LWhEeGJhdXhlMjljc3l5dWVka0w=
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:9000
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Header**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 68
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 22 Mar 2019 05:38:23 GMT
Server: NA
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

**Server Copmonent**
The server component is built using camel and maven restlet.

```
from(reslet://routeName)
.log("${in.headers}"; // the auth header is completely ignored.
```

The app is deployed in tomcat and the web.xml has filters as below

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization, Cache-Control</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
 </filter>
 <filter>
        <filter-name>envHttpHeaders</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>envHttpHeaders</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Am also behind a Corporate proxy. Does it rip off Auth header**

Comment: To be able to help you, we'll need the code you use to extract the header and the setup you use (do you use any gateways, reverse proxies, ... that could potentially strip headers from the request).

Comment: The server component is a camel with maven restlet. I immediately print the headers after the route starts. Edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the last line in my question

**Am also behind a Corporate proxy. Does it rip off Auth header**

After testing the same application in a personal computer with open internet connection, am  convinced the, the corporate proxy is actually removing few headers for security reasons.